# Javascript validation works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, compatibility

Here is the **js** code

```
function isCharKey(evt){

 var charCode = event.keyCode
   if ((charCode > 64  && charCode <91 )|| (charCode >96 && charCode<123) || (charCode==32))
    return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here is the **html** code

```
<label id="exe_form_name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="tbcust_name"  id="name1" onkeypress="return isCharKey(event);">
```

Comment: where is `event` variable....It is not `event` use `evt` .Use `var charCode = evt.keyCode`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var charCode = event.keyCode
```

to

```
var charCode = evt.keyCode
```

Comment: Chrome implements a global "event" object, where as Firefox doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

function isCharKey(evt)
{

var charCode = evt.keyCode
   if ((charCode > 64  && charCode <91 )|| (charCode >96 && charCode<123) || (charCode==32))
    return true;
    return false;
}

Comment: <label id="exe_form_name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="tbcust_name"  id="name1" onkeydown="return isCharKey(event);">

Comment: Use in label onkeydown and use var charCode = evt.keyCode;

Comment: thank you vishnu, its working but when i type something and if i press backspace to clear the typed content its not taking the backspace

Comment: if ((charCode > 64 && charCode <91 )|| (charCode >96 && charCode<123) || (charCode==32) || (charCode==8))

Comment: Try this add one more condition on the your javascript if case || (charCode==8) then it will work properly as per your requirement.